# Strip before heading left side not working in mobile view exactly

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a heading with a left side strip line; it's working fine in desktop but not looking fine in mobile view, in mobile strip line override the heading, how do I make this work in responsive (mobile) views?

[image]

```css
.title {
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "Open Sans"!important;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    clear: both;
    margin-left:50px;
}
.strip {
    background-color: #ffc20e;
    width: 87%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 31px;
    border-radius: initial!important;
    left: -1010px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 550px)
.strip {
    left: -356px!important;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="title"><span class="strip"></span>Heading</h4>
```

Comment: where is the line?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and given your prompt time much appreciated! Yellow strip line left before heading

Answer (score 0):

there is no need of any media query!

```css
.title {
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "Open Sans"!important;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    clear: both;
}
.strip {
    background-color: #ffc20e;
    width: 110px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 25px;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){\
  .title {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .strip {
    width: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h4 class="title"><span class="strip"></span>Heading</h4>
```

Comment: Thank for your time...It is not working in mobile view it comes under the container I just want strip outside the container

Comment: you need to decrease the size of strip and font-size of the heading for result.